# emphatic sentence or relative clause

Tags: syntactic-analysis, relative-clauses, sentence-patterns

Are the following sentences emphatic sentence or relative clause? Why? What's the difference?

> It is the factory that you visited last week.
>
> It is Tom who/that I saw yesterday.

Thanks for your englightenment.

Answer (score -1):

The sentences are *not* relative clauses. A clause is a *part* of a sentence which *could* form a sentence in its own right. That is it contains, at least, a subject and a verb (although the subject may be implied).

The sentences, however, both *contain* and *are examples of the use of* relative clauses joined to the main clause by the subordinating conjunction *that*. The relative clauses are "you visited last week" (which qualifies the factory) and "I saw yesterday" (which qualifies Tom).

Comment: Why aren't they emphatic sentences?

Comment: I had to look up 'emphatic sentences', it's not a term I recognise. Internet searches did not return much apart from the 'it is' form [like this](https://englishelxna2.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/cleft-sentences/). In this case I would say that the given sentences are both **emphatic** sentences which _include_ **relative clauses**.